# how to intersect a list and a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that looks like this:

```
set(['loc. 08652', 'loc. 14331', 'loc. 08650', 'loc.06045', 'loc.10160', 'loc. 08656']
```

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                             lung     heart      kidney 
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.08652  32.406993  51.709692  15.883315  
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.14331   5.255465  86.048540   8.695995  
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.12124  34.730648  39.070967  26.198384 
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.06045  50.992902  28.701922  20.305177 
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.10160  27.619962  63.702141   8.677896  
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.20210  45.148668  43.700587  11.150744
```

How can I conveniently produce intersect the two files, and output a data frame like that below:

```
                             lung     heart      kidney 
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.08652  32.406993  51.709692  15.883315  
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.14331   5.255465  86.048540   8.695995  
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.06045  50.992902  28.701922  20.305177 
asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.10160  27.619962  63.702141   8.677896
```

Comment: Look at [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). You'll basically do something like: `new_df = df[df.index.isin(my_set_of_locators)]`, after forcing those elements in your `set` to match the structure of your data frame's index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clean your index, i.e. remove extra strings before `loc`, and then use `isin` method as suggested by @not_a_robot:

```
s = set(['loc.08652', 'loc.14331', 'loc.08650', 'loc.06045', 'loc.10160', 'loc. 08656']
# the set has been cleaned here so that it doesn't contain spaces

df[df.index.str.replace(".*(?=loc)", "").isin(s)]
```

[image]